# how to create circle button programmatically and set it's position

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

How to create a circle button and set it's position pogrammatically?
I'm trying to create an array of buttons and set their positions, but somewhy the code isn't working in the right way. All the buttons appear in 1 place and they're not circles.

```
    private void addButtons(int hLimit, int vLimit)
    {
        dotButton[] dotsArray = new dotButton[hLimit * vLimit];

        int scale = 30;
        int yStart = 100;
        int xStart = 50;
        int yEnd = yStart + (hLimit - 1)*scale;
        int xEnd = xStart + (vLimit - 1)*scale;


        for (int i = 0; i < hLimit; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < vLimit; ++j)
            {
                int id = j*hLimit + i;
                dotsArray[id] = new dotButton(id, j, i);
                dotsArray[id].Width = Width = 10;
                dotsArray[id].Height = Height = 10;
                dotsArray[id].Style = Resources["Sircle Button"] as Style;
                dotsArray[id].Click += new RoutedEventHandler(dotClick);
                double x = xStart + j * scale - Width/2;
                double y = yStart + i * scale - Height/2;
                dotsArray[id].Margin = new Thickness(x, y, x + Width, y + Height);

                myGrid.Children.Add(dotsArray[id]);
            }
        }
    }
```

dotButton is a class for buttons that I wrote

```
    public class dotButton : Button
{
    private int id;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }

    public dotButton(int ID, int X, int Y)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, as the applications starts it looks like this. Why is that happening?

[image]

Comment: What does your XAML look like?

Comment: @Sam 
<Window x:Name="myWindow" x:Class="Points_The_Game.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Dots The Game" Height="740" Width="690">
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Width="680" Height="720">
        
    </Grid>
</Window>

Comment: Have a look at this http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/circular-wpf-button-template.html

Comment: And still, why does it look so weird after setup?